# Why is migration.json file not being generated after running the nx migrate latest command?

Tags: angular, migrate, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

```
 nx migrate @nrwl/angular@15.0.0
Fetching meta data about packages.
It may take a few minutes.
Fetching @nrwl/angular@15.0.0
Fetching @nrwl/angular@15.0.0

 >  NX   The migrate command has run successfully.

   - Package.json has been updated.
   - There are no migrations to run, so migrations.json has not been created.


 >  NX   Next steps:

   - Make sure package.json changes make sense and then run 'yarn',
   - To learn more go to https://nx.dev/core-features/automate-updating-dependencies
```

Expecting: "a migration.json file has been created successfully"

Comment: same problem here.. have you solved your problem?

Comment: I am also getting this and I'm clearly not on the latest version...... most annoying.. the last in a long line of NX issues (much as I love it)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same situation. Running the command `nx repair` solved it.
https://nx.dev/packages/nx/documents/repair

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `nx migrate @nrwl/workspace` if the repair command does not works..

Comment: And then run nx migrate latest or whatever version you want to migrate to